# save images loaded from url in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection

I have loaded images in `UITableView` from URLs. Now how can I save these images in my **iPhone**.

As you download an image, create a thumbnail of it with a proper naming convention and save it as well.

please provide some hint or methods for this saving images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// data is the NSData you obtained
// from the NSURLConnection

UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

// path is an NSString containing the path
// to save the file, usually inside Documents, Cache, etc,

[image writeToFile:path];
```

*Read Apple's docs on how to get the paths to relevant directories.

Comment: no actually i wish to download images in phone memory ..i have already loaded images from url

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying, and you have accepted an answer that is basically the same, but more detailed.

Comment: ok leave that question.can u help me in making grid view?   i have created a code for grid view but it loads only single image for all and now i want to load multiple images into the grid view from the url.how to do that?

Comment: You should probably post a new question.

Comment: ya i have posted but nobody answerd on that

Comment: `writeToFile` is method of `NSData` not of `UIImage`

Answer (score 2):

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://image.com"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
```

more information about **UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum** you can find [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to download the image from image's weburl and save it inside the application.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imageURL];
 [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *localFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.jpg"];
 NSData *thedata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
 [thedata writeToFile:localFilePath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: And how can I insert multiple images from url into that??